# Select databases from one table and Insert specific value into databases returned

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a unique situation where I have a table of all databases. I want to dynamically insert something in all of my databases returned from query in my db1 database.

```
SELECT db FROM db1.databases
```

If I run above query directly in Mysql Workbench I get list of databases but bellow is what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT db FROM db1.databases) AS `db`.`events`
(`date`,`description`)
VALUES ('2019--01-01','New Year');
```

I have 'event' table in every database, right now I manually paste database name instead of 'db' but it is time taking as there are tens of databases.
I searched Stackoverflow but I only found queries like following which I don't need as there is only two databases and I don't want to insert one table into another.

```
INSERT INTO newDatabase.table1 (Column1, Column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM oldDatabase.table1;
```

Or maybe if there is any stored procedure loop? I'm not good in stored procedure.

Comment: Note: `2019--01-01` is not a valid date.

Comment: If you've got *N* databases you are on your own here. That's not a relational design that MySQL is prepared to work with.

Comment: You need a stored procedure with a loop which creates and executes a prepared statement for each db it finds in  db1.databases. = though why you have db1.databases is unclear when information_schema.schemata contains all schema names,

Comment: @P.Salmon you are right it is the same as information_scheme, the reason for db1 is because db1 is as my general database where I store little more info of my customers such as customer-name and database-name etc.  and each customer has unique database where they have Event table.  Yes I think stored procedure is the only way and I've to figure it out.
tadman what do you mean by N database?